# Why are the new Titanium Grid fins not used on all Falcon 9 landings?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, landing, recovery, grid-fins

With the Block 4 version of the Falcon 9, one of the new features is the Titanium Grid fins, vs the previously used Aluminium fins.

However, not all Block 4 flights have used the Ti vs Al fins.

Is there a reason?

Check [this question and answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22096/how-are-the-spacex-falcon-9-mod-3-and-mod-4-grid-fins-different) for a great set of images of the two types of fins.

Answer (score 8):

Musk tweeted an answer to a question.

[Musk Tweet](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/942526513731260417) in which he wrote:

> For now, we only use those on super hot reentry missions. Will go to all Ti with Falcon 9 V5, which is a few months away.

So the Block 5 (v5/mod5/Falcon 9 1.3) that is due soon enough, designed for rapid reuse will be the full time target. Until then they are using the cheaper ones, which undoubtedly they have a supply of, to use up in flights on easier landing missions.

Comment: Nice to see my tweet be the genesis for a StackExchange post :)

Comment: @ReactingToAngularVues If you can get Musk to respond, you can get MANY questions on StackExchange!  :)  Was a great response you elicited, keep up the good work!